# Can't use updated state in function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently using `Agents.tsx` as a parent function and `StickyFilter.tsx` as the child. I am setting a state with an initial value of an empty string in `Agents.tsx` like so:

```js
const Agents = (props: AgentsProps): ReactElement => {

    const { agentsMode, recruitClient, recruitGlobals, setRecruitClient, setShowLoading } = props;

    const [savedSearchName, setSavedSearchName] = useState(''); // set state here
```

I then am passing that `setSavedSearchName` as a prop to `StickyFilter.tsx`:

```js
const StickyFilter = (props: StickyFilterProps): ReactElement => {

    const { otherProps,
        setSavedSearchName
    } = props;
```

later down in `StickFilter.tsx` I am calling on that state function like so:

```
const setSavedSearch = (savedSearch: RecruitAgentSearch): void => {

        let revisedSearches: AgentSearch[] = [];
        // Redacted code -- bunch of logic 

        // Value gets set here
        setSavedSearchName(revisedSearchDetails.criteria.searchName || '');

    };
```

Once that value gets set in `StickyFilter.tsx` I am able to have it console log in the parent component just fine. I have a table that renders and once I click on a certain item it fires off the `saveNewNote` function, but for some reason the function is still pulling in the empty string but whenever I click on the item a SECOND time, it'll pull in the right value. What am I missing here? I tried inputting a `useEffect` hook like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(savedSearchName)
    }, [savedSearchName]);
```

but it will not console log the correct value until I do the action on the table a second time.

Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: Here is the `saveNewNote` function in `Agents.tsx`

```
const saveNewNote = async (agent: Agent, agentsMode: AgentsMode): Promise<void> => {
// just trying to console log here after the state is set
        console.log(savedSearchName); // returning empty string
        console.log(recruitStoreApi.savedSearchName);
        console.log(stateApi);

// Simple logic redacted
        }
```

Comment: can you add where you are using saveNewNote function and how is it defined

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Sure thing. I've added it to the the original post. Its basically just me trying to console log the new state. Added comments for clarification on the code itself too. `saveNewNote` does get passed down as a prop to the table too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the data structure that injects into the table. I could not find a way to get the latest state.